# CultureInfo values differ between applications for the same culture. Is this a bug?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a strange issue occurring on my Windows 8 dev box. The following line of code results in two different values for the NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator when comparing an ASP .NET application running Kentico and a console application (both running on .NET 4.0).

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA");
var separator = culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
```

The value of seperator:

1. Kentico application: "," <- comma
2. Console application: "." <- period

The correct output for my regional setting is a period.

How is this possible? When I first picked up a formatting issue for decimal numbers, I thought it may have been a Kentico bug, however this test indicates otherwise. How is it possible that a new instance of CultureInfo for a specific locale returns an instance that differs across applications?

Comment: Are you compiling using the same framework version?

Comment: Yes, both compiled using .NET 4.0

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645441/asp-net-application-doesnt-reflect-regional-settings

Comment: @Rohland No probs, glad the link helped.

Comment: This is seemingly caused by the OS. Win 7 uses PERIOD, Win 8 uses COMMA. I submitted a bug report. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/841012/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Jason Evans's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127440/jason-evans) comment pointed me in the right direction. See the link he posted: [ASP.NET application doesn't reflect Regional settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645441/asp-net-application-doesnt-reflect-regional-settings)

It turns out that regional settings are stored **per user** in Windows. This is something I should have been aware of. Updating the application pool to run as myself produced the same result across both applications.

To be fair, what is still confusing is how Network Service (the account the application pool was running under) came to have the incorrect value. I'm not even sure how I'd rectify that.

Edit:

If you need to update the regional settings for reserved accounts. You have two options.

1. Control Panel > Regional Settings > Click the administrative tab and then select "Copy Settings". On the screen that launches, ensure you check "Welcome Screen and system accounts". Older versions of Windows are similar I believe.
2. For the brave. Registry: HKEY_USERS > SID... > Control Panel > International. The security identifier for Network Service is: SID: S-1-5-20.

Ensure you restart the application pool for settings to take effect.

Comment: unfortunately solution # 1 doesnt work on windows 10

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Note that this *wasn't* the issue - but in other cases it could be, so I'm leaving it here for posterity.

I strongly suspect that the console application *isn't* running on .NET 4.0. It's easy enough to verify that using `Environment.Version` though. Here's a short console app and results via two different versions of the framework:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA");
        string separator = culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", Environment.Version);
        Console.WriteLine("Separator: {0}", separator);
    }
}
```

Compiling against .NET 4.5:

```
Version: 4.0.30319.18010
Separator: ,
```

Compiling against .NET 2.0:

```
Version: 2.0.50727.6400
Separator: .
```

Try this code in both applications, and see what versions they're running.

Comment: No, I get the same result for both apps for version number:  4.0.30319.18010.

Comment: That's surprising. What about `Environment.Is64BitProcess`? Admittedly it would be odd for the architecture to make a difference, but you never know...

Comment: Thanks Jon. Turned out to be simple in the end. I didn't think to run both under my account. Turns out regional settings are user specific. Somehow my Network Service account had a tweaked set of values.

Comment: @Rohland: Right - I'll leave this answer up for future readers but edit appropriately.

Comment: This was an OS change in Windows 8. Just got bitten by it. :(