# Default decimal separator on IIS

Tags: c#, validation, iis, decimal, locale

I'm facing a rather weird issue. I have an **ASP.Net** website that basically allows users to deposit money into a fake account. I have some validation on the input amounts and it has a min value of **0.00**. However, when I load the page and check "min value" it is **0,00** - so when the check happens on the backend the min value is **0,00 (note the separator)** and it breaks/is invalid.

**I set VS to use the correct culture** in my config, I have set **my decimal to default to use a full stop separator** system side (in region/locale settings) and my **IIS .Net Globalization is set to use the correct culture**. However, whenever I load a page it defaults to 0,00 instead of 0.00. Is there anywhere else I need to change it?

When my friend hosts the same site on his PC the min value is 0.00 - we've checked and all our number formats and culture stuff seems the same. Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: Are you sure? HTML5-validation (<input type="number" min="0.00" step="0.01">) uses invariant culture ("0.00") while parsing the attributes and posting the data, but the data _presented_ should match your local system where you're running the browser. Could you verify using Firebug/developer tools that the value posted actually contains a comma?

Comment: It definitely is a comma - just double checked :/

Comment: What exactly did your set in web.config? Please post the line and the name of the section.

Comment: If someone have the same issue, this solution work for me :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322910/cultureinfo-values-differ-between-applications-for-the-same-culture-is-this-a-b

Answer (score 6):

Your Windows/.NET Framework is probably a non-English installation? Did you use this line in your web.config

Example for US English:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
        ...
```

See: [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: 12 hours man, 12 hours... Thanks