# Why can't we assign Localization to ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: iis, localization, applicationpoolidentity

I've been investigating some localization issues with our web application and even though I start to understand the problems and the way to solve them... I still have a couple of questions I failed to find a decent answer to.

It would be great of some people can point me out to appropriate documentation for me to read up and understand more the concept of ApplicationPoolIdentity.

What I understand so far:
There are 2 ways to make your web application Localization-aware based on your requirements.

1) Configure in the web.config file (Globalization) or in the IIS UI for the specific website.

- This works great, except it does not pick up Globalization on IIS-level when website is Auto Detect or Invariant Culture? What's the hierarchy it's using?

2) Configure Localization for the user under which the IIS process is running.

- You need to copy the Localization settings to the system accounts ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322910/cultureinfo-values-differ-between-applications-for-the-same-culture-is-this-a-b/14323336#14323336))
- You then need to run the apppool under one of these accounts (local, Networkservice, LocalService...)
- It does not seem to work when running under ApplicationPoolIdentity

ApplicationPoolIdentity is a *virtual* user account, assuming that's why it's not picked up by the copy-to action in Localization.
Although, it's not working either when I say Copy-To-New-Accounts.

So what Localization is the ApplicationPoolIdentity using???
It seems the default one based on the Windows Installation, am I right here?

If anyone can correct me and answer my questions, or link to some more documentation around this. Really appreciated.