# Regional settings issue in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regional

i'm from turkey. our date format is : dd/mm/yyyy

when i execute datetime.now command in my localhost result is 15.01.2013. i mean true.

but in my web server result is 01.15.2013. server regional settings is ok. Localization and other settings is set to turkey.

so? where is the problem i don't understand. and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645441/asp-net-application-doesnt-reflect-regional-settings

Answer (score 0):

The regional settings on your local computer seem to differ from the regional settings on your server.

You should probably pass a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) to your ToString call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx
or explicity use a `FormatString` like this:

```
.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```