# ASP.NET generated code: where does "dateorder" come from?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, globalization

For background, we are in the process of upgrading to Windows Server 2012 R2, and testing revealed that some date input textboxes on our ASP.NET site aren't working as intended.  The textboxes have a CompareValidator defined for them to check if one date is later than the other.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator3" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtStartDate"
ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" ErrorMessage="..." Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date"
Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

This CompareValidator is failing all the time now, on Windows Server 2012, whereas the old site hosted on Windows Server 2008 did not have this problem.  I have done some digging and I think the most likely culprit is the change in default date format for the Canada region in Windows Server 2012.  In the generated code for the page, the DOM element for the validator has a property "dateorder" that's always being set to "ymd".  This value is "dmy" on the old site.

```
...
cutoffyear: "2029"
dataset: DOMStringMap
dateorder: "ymd"
dir: ""
display: "Dynamic"
...
```

Because our inputs take date strings like "01/01/2015", the "ymd" pattern is not matched and the validator returns false.  I have changed the date format settings everywhere that I can think of, and even tried changing the IIS site's .NET Globalization settings to use another culture (en-GB), and nothing has worked.  I'm really curious as to where this "ymd" setting comes from, and how to change it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"dateorder" comes from `BaseCompareValidator` which essentially reads `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
string pattern = dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
string dateorder = (pattern.StartsWith ("y", true, Helpers.InvariantCulture) ? "ymd" : (pattern.StartsWith ("m", true, Helpers.InvariantCulture) ? "mdy" : "dmy"));
```

Now the gotcha as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645441/asp-net-application-doesnt-reflect-regional-settings), is that Regional Settings is per-user and you might want to check the account the Application Pool was running under.

Comment: We tried changing the setting for the app pool user but still no dice. After a lot of head scratching, we finally found the culprit, which is our CMS that stores culture settings for each page. All the IIS and system settings are overridden by these.

Comment: By the way, where did you get that code segment for the `BaseCompareValidator`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody changed the date format in the Windows OS on the old computer?  But how about trying to force it within your application...my idea is to do it in the Global.asax file (you may have to add that file to the root of the application if it is not already there).  Then, something like this:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  CultureInfo myCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  myCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
  myCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCulture;
}
```

Comment: Edited because I thought that you wanted ymd instead of dmy.

Comment: We tried this without success, possibly because of the culture settings in our CMS.  After debugging the global code to make sure it ran, we inspected the CurrentCulture on a page, and the date format is not the one we set it to. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change sort date from control panel regional setting. Dateorder and cutoffyear etc attribute are used by validation JavaScript generated by .net for validator control to function on browser. Value of these comes from server settings. IIS only picks as per server config and generats HTML.